# What is this yellow, four-petal flowering plant in Lynchburg, VA?

Tags: identification, flowers

This grows wild behind my house. It has many yellow flowers per "branch", and many branches. The flowers bloom after each other. The flowers have 4 petals. Each seed pod has a flower on top of it.

[image: flower]
[image: plant]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the previous answer suggests (vote given), its Evening Primrose, also known as Sundrop or Evening Star - Oenethera biennis to be precise - seeds itself freely. This native, naturally occurring one has 4 bi lobed petals, as in your picture, although these days, it's possible to buy 'new and improved' varieties created by breeders.

The pods left behind by spent flowers are tapered towards the end, three quarters to one and a half inches long, with 8 tiny erect lobes at the tip, black seeds inside if it's this plant.

Seed pods, green and dry, and ripe seeds:

[image][image][image]

Flowers, and entire plant:

[image][image]

Comment: the seedpods are about an inch long, tapered, and have lots of tiny black seeds in them.

Comment: @Bamboo I downvoted because the OP said, "It has many yellow flowers per "branch", and many branches.". *Oenethera biennis* doesn't have 'many branches', but each stem usually emerges from the ground. But it appears the OP made a mistake, so I'll take the vote back.

Comment: @JMusser - well forgive me for pointing out the perfectly ... obvious, but the picture the OP posted told a different story, surely?! Did you not study the image before clicking on the vote? And you know I always like an explanation in case I can learn summat new...

Comment: @Bamboo well, from my phone, the pictures the OP posted looked a lot like my answer below, hence my answer. :) As for the vote explanation, please see above.

Comment: @J.Musser, hmm, well maybe you shouldn't vote from, nor do ID Qs from your phone- a picture speaks a thousand words...

Comment: @J.Musser, bamboo: I'll try to check tonight to confirm the one/many flower per branch/stem issue.

Comment: @antony.trupe - don't worry on my account, I never take written descriptions to be gospel anyway - someone yesterday was asking what this white flowered tree was, luckily with a photo, and they weren't flowers, they were leaves, so plenty of license must always be given to descriptions

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me strongly of some species of [Erysimum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erysimum). This genus contains the common wallflower.

I think the flowers, buds, seedpods, growth habit, and leaves match, but your picture isn't the greatest. :)

I found a comparison picture that looks very similar:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

That looks like an [evening primrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oenothera) in the second photograph. If those green pods form after the blossom is pollinated, that would be a clue.